# Why isn't isnumber search not working correctly with given data?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get Excel to search for a series of keywords in title using the `ISNUMBER()` search function, but it's bringing back all `FALSE`, which is wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated:

I made sure I F4'd the item list -- still wrong

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(R2,$G$2:$G$22))
```

Comment: Did you enter the formula into a 21x1 range at once, [using Ctrl+Shift+Enter](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/create-an-array-formula-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d)?

Answer (score 0):

Use MATCH:

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&R2&"*",$G$2:$G$22,0))
```

[image]

With the Search set up the way you have it, it will only return the value of the first in the list.  You can wrap SUMPRODUCT around the formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(R2,$G$2:$G$22)))>0
```

But that is more intensive then the simple MATCH.

This assumes that the Keyword that is being looked-up is in R2 and the range `$G$2:$G$22` us the list of titles.

If it is the other way around then the SEARCH is backwards and should be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($G$2:$G$22,R2)))>0
```

[image]

Comment: That does a completely different thing from what the OP was doing.

Comment: @gserg, no it is not, he wants to know if R2 is anywhere in the values in `$G$2:$G$22`  Which the MATCH using wildcards does also.

Comment: @GSerg but I did miss the `,0` in the match.

Comment: `Match` returns a single (first) entry from `$G$2:$G$22` that contains the value. The OP has an array of matches (*"bringing back all FALSE"*), one per cell in `$G$2:$G$22`, that shows if the respective cell contains the value.

Comment: If you go by the way he set up the SEARCH function, `SEARCH(FindText,WithinText)` then one must assume the key work is in R2 and the list of Titles are in `$G$2:$G$22`, and the OP wants to know if that keyword is in the list of titles.  If so, return TRUE.  The Match does that.  If the Key word in R2 is found in any of the List of titles, then Match will return a number and return TRUE.  If it was the other way around the SEARCH is in the wrong order.

Comment: `The Match does that` - The match does that once per array. The intention was to do that 21 times per array yielding 21 true/falses. The OP's formula does that if entered with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Comment: That is not what the Search formula is doing nor did the OP explain that.  I understand that the formula is referring to R2 as it is the relative cell.  It would be placed in row 2 and copied down so the next iteration is `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(R3,$G$2:$G$22))` and so forth.  I do not see anywhere that the OP has stated something that contradicts my assumption.